# How to add a Calendar filter for my Pivot Table?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, timeline

I am building a pivot table in excel for work. Is there a way where I can build a calendar slicer, where someone can click on (for example) the 30th of September, and update the pivot table?

The columns I have are:

1. Product
2. City
3. Start date
4. End date

Disclaimer: I am not looking for slicers. These are not user friendly since I have 2 date columns Start and End dates

I tried slicers, but these werent good enough. If I had a product sell only 1 day of August for example, it would show as all the month.